# Load data into external text file using django

Tags: python, mysql, django, jenkins

I have apache+mysql+django. in mysql I store some data, and use django to interact with it.
Now I need to store data from mysql into some external text file(like csv) in a propper format(I want to parse it later with jenkins as a source to parameters). How can I create some kind of event which will upload data from DB table into text file using Django(as far as I already have Django installed, and I know python itself can do this easy)?
And I want reapetable event. Like every 1 minute data will be synced. Smthng like this.

Tnaks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing a custom management command that takes the information you want and writes it to your CSV. As you said, the process of writing data to a text file is easy enough in Python - using a management command would let you use the ORM directly, greatly simplifying your interaction with the database.

The second benefit of using a management command is that it's easy to run as a cronjob. Once you've written your custom command (let's call it `csvsync`), you can write something like this in your crontab:

```
* * * * * python /your/path/to/manage.py csvsync
```

Here's the relevant documentation for custom management commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/

The developers note the following in the linked docs:

> **Standalone scripts**
>
> Custom management commands are especially useful for running
>   standalone scripts or for scripts that are periodically executed from
>   the UNIX crontab or from Windows scheduled tasks control panel.